# How could I design a turing machine that prints all natural numbers on its tape in order?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

How one could implement a turing machine that prints all natural numbers of its tape in order. Two consecutive numbers are separated on the tape with the symbol #. The tape should look like this:

## #0#00#000#0000#00000#...

the number of 0s is the natural number.

Answer (score 1):

I would design it out of two components:

The first component copies the "previous" string, i.e. the string between the second and first appearance of # to the left of the string. You can do this by moving left until you reach the first #, then left until you meet the first non-zero, then move one right, replace the $0$ with $1$, and move right to write $0$. When this is all done, replace all the ones with zeroes.

This should produce something like this:

```
#0#00#000#  ---> #0#00#100#0 ---> #0#00#110#00  --> #0#00#111#000 --> #0#00#000#000
```

The second component writes a 0# at the end of the string.

Comment: How does the machine starts writing the first one or three natural numbers ? the tape is initially empty.

Comment: @Altaïr You can have one component that simply writes `#0#` in the beginning, then puts the head down right of the right #. Then, run the components I describe.

Comment: @Altaïr Just have a number of initial states which do your initialization which it never returns to.